SQLite: Matching All Items Within a List of Characters
I am working with a table (essentially a list of words, i.e. a dictionary'), and had the need to create a subset of items from that table that only contained 3 certain characters, let's say, 'A', 'P', and 'Z'.
Obviously, I can use GLOB or LIKE, like so:
WHERE Word LIKE '%A%' AND Word LIKE '%P%' AND Word LIKE '%P%'
...but I seem to recall once doing a similar thing with a single GLOB statement, although I cannot locate the code where I did that. After a search of the web, and even a consultation with ChatGPT (which informs me that it's not possible, for whatever that's worth!), I thought I'd ask here.
I attempted various combinations of GLOB patterns using NOT and the ^ negation character, all to no avail, although I seem to recall that this is how I once successfully tackled the problem.

And, would you know it, I just recalled the project where I did this, but I'm leaving the question up as it's probably interesting to somebody!
SELECT Word 
FROM Words 
WHERE NOT 'ZAP' GLOB '*[^' || Word || ']*';

Basically, swap the 'search in' term with the 'search for' term, and use NOT with the ^ operator.
I knew I wasn't going crazy!
